# Can't unload com.apple.CommCenter.plist on iphone4 with ios 6.1.2?

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, darwin

In my OpenSSh terminal, I input the command

```
 "launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.CommCenter.plist"
```

But the terminal shows that "nothing found to unload".And When I input the command :

```
launchctl list
```

I find com.apple.CommCenter is in such condition：

```
84  -   com.apple.CommCenter
```

so，Dose any one know why I can't unload the com.apple.commcenter.plist.Thanks!

Comment: Are you running the unload command as the root user, or as mobile?

Comment: Hmmm.  That works for me (on iOS 6.1).  Have you tried unloading **other** daemons with that command?  Do they all fail to unload?  Is `nothing found to unload` the *only* output you see, or is there more?

Comment: @Nate No,it seems that some other plists can be unloaded such as com.apple.BlueTool.plist.but  only the com.apple.CommCenter.plist and a plist named com.apple.CommCenterClassic.plist can't unload,the later's  result is the same as com.apple.CommCenter.plist~~~~

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:
Physically change directories, then unload once you get there.

```
cd /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/
launchctl unload -w com.apple.CommCenter.plist
```